# Unable to allocate 329. MiB for an array with shape (86245376,) and data type int32

Tags: python, numpy

How to get around the above problem? What type of array do I use to avoid it?

I wanted to store the variable quadrant in a list array after running a series of mathematical operations. But every time I run this function, I come across this error.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
quadrant_list = []
azimuth = phi_vals
polar_angles = theta_vals

def determine_quadrant(azimuth, polar_angle):
  if azimuth >= 0 and azimuth < np.pi / 2:
      if polar_angle >= 0 and polar_angle < np.pi / 2:
          quadrant = 1 #A
      else:
          quadrant = 4 #D
  elif azimuth >= np.pi / 2 and azimuth < np.pi:
      if polar_angle >= 0 and polar_angle < np.pi / 2:
         quadrant = 2 #B
      else:
         quadrant = 4 #D
 elif azimuth >= np.pi and azimuth < 3 * np.pi / 2:
     if polar_angle >= 0 and polar_angle < np.pi / 2:
         quadrant = 2 #B
     else:
         quadrant = 3 #C
else:
     if polar_angle >= 0 and polar_angle < np.pi / 2:
        quadrant = 1 #A
     else:
         quadrant = 3 #C
return quadrant





for azimuth, polar_angle in zip(phi_vals, theta_vals):
   q = determine_quadrant(phi_vals, theta_vals)
   quadrant_list.append(q)
```

Comment: What's a variable quadrant? Please add your [mcve] so we can see what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I put my code in the main question. I am trying to calculate the quadrant number for my spherical coordinates based on the azimuth and the polar angles. However, I keep running into this error.

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: It is this line: q = determine_quadrant(phi_vals, theta_vals)